# How can I put something on the top right corner to make that gap blend in with the header?

Tags: html, css

With your help, community of stack overflow, I created an HTML "sandwich", with a scrollable table and a static header, the only thing that I still need to "fix" is that white gap on the top right corner (**right above the scrolling bar**). I would like to make it blend in with the header to make it look like one thing, without messing the table.

May you help me?

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function(){

    $( "#btfirst" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-first"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btfirst").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});

    $( "#btprev" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-prev"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btprev").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});


    $( "#btnext" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-next"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btnext").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});


    $( "#btlast" ).button({
      icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-seek-end"
      },
      text: false
    });
    $("#btlast").css({'height': '1.2em','margin':'1px'});
 
 $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");

 
});
```

```css
            /*the following HTML and body rule sets are required only if using a % width or height*/
    HTML {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    @font-face {
     font-family: 'agroverdanab';
     src: url('./fonts/agroverdanab.eot');
     src: local('agroverdanab'), url('./fonts/agroverdanab.ttf') format('truetype');


     font-family: 'agroverdana';
     src: url('./fonts/agroverdana.eot');
     src: local('agroverdana'), url('./fonts/agroverdana.ttf') format('truetype');
    }

    body {
  float:center;
  border: 1px solid #9BC2E6;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 99.4%;
        height: 99%;
  margin:0.3% 0.3% 0.3% 0.3%;
    }
    .scrollingtable {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: auto; /*if you want a fixed width, set it here, else set to auto*/
        min-width: 100%; /*if you want a % width, set it here, else set to 0*/
        height: 100%; /*set table height here; can be fixed value or %*/
        min-height: 100%/*104px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows + caption + thead*/
        font-family: 'agroverdana';
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding: 1px 0 100px 0; /*need enough padding to make room for caption*/
        text-align: left;
        }
    .scrollingtable * {box-sizing: border-box;}
    .scrollingtable > div {
        position: relative;
        border-top: 1px solid white; /*The header's border-top*/
  margin-left:2px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 20px; /*this determines column header height*/
        }
    .scrollingtable > div:before {
        top: 0;
        background: #9BC2E6; /*header row background color | header color*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div:before,
    .scrollingtable > div > div:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div {
        min-height: 0/*43px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows*/
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow: scroll/*auto*/; /*set to auto if using fixed or % width; else scroll*/
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border: 1px solid white; /*border around table body*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div:after {background: white;} /*match page background color*/
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table {
        width: 100%;
        border-spacing: 0;
        margin-top: -20px; /*inverse of column header height*/
        margin-right: 1px; /*uncomment if using % width*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > caption {
        font-size:15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px; /*inverse of caption height*/
        margin-top: -1px; /*inverse of border-width*/
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > * > tr > * {padding: 0;}
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 6px 0 6px; /*header cell padding*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > :first-child:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
        border-left: 1px solid #9BC2E6; /*leftmost header border*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        color: black; /*header row font color | AKA text color*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:after {content: attr(label);}
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        min-height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
        padding-top: 1px;
        border-left: 2px solid white; /*borders between header cells*/
    }
    .scrollingtable .scrollbarhead {float: right;}
    .scrollingtable .scrollbarhead:before {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        top: -1px; /*inverse border-width*/
        background: white; /*match page background color | Right corner*/ 
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:after {
        content: "";
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid white; /*Can become an issue if handled badly*/
        top: -1px; /*inverse of border width*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr {background: white;} /*White lines*/
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * {
        border-bottom: 1px solid white; /*Horizontal lines*/
        padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
        height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
    }
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody:last-of-type > tr:last-child > * {border-bottom: none;}
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background: #DDEBF7;} /*alternate row color*/
    .scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * + * {border-left: 2px solid white;} /*borders between body cells AKA columns*/

    .scrollingtable > div:before {
        top: 0;
        background: #9BC2E6; /*header row background color | header color*/
    }

    .thead_prop, .tbody_prop{

        font-family: 'agroverdana';
        font-size:13px;

    }
 
 #content{left:1px;border-top:solid 1px #9BC2E6;border-bottom:solid 1px #9BC2E6;flex:1;}
 #navbar{padding:3px 4px 3px 2px} /*top | right | bottom | left*/
 #navbutton{float:right;}
 #vpad-pesq{float:left;}
 #searching{margin-left:2px;padding-top:2px;}
 #msgbar{border-top:solid 1px #9BC2E6;border-bottom:solid 1px #9BC2E6;height:3%;}
 #footer{border-top:solid 1px #9BC2E6;border-top:0;height:5%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<style>.scrollingtable > div > div > table {margin-right: 17px;}</style>
<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
 
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
 <title>Central de Controle da Engenharia</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 
    </head>
    <body>
        
  <header style="padding-bottom:5px;text-align:center;">Central de Controle da Engenharia</header>

  <section id="content">
   <header id="navbar">
   
    <input type="text" id="vpad-pesq"/>
     <select id="searching">
       <option>Código</option>
       <option>Nome</option>
     </select>
   
    <div id="navbutton">
     <button id="btfirst"></button>
     <button id="btprev"></button>
     <button id="btnext"></button>
     <button id="btlast"></button>
    </div>
    
   </header>
  </section>

  
        <div class="scrollingtable">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="thead_prop">
                                    <div label="Código"></div>
                                </th>
                                <th class="thead_prop">
                                    <div label="Descrição"></div>
                                </th>
                        

                                <th class="scrollbarhead"/>
                                <!--ALWAYS ADD THIS EXTRA CELL AT END OF HEADER ROW-->
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       <tr class="tbody_prop">
                                <td>001</td>
    <td>Coxa c/ sobrecoxa s/ osso s/ pele</td>
                            </tr>
       
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
       <!-- pode colocar text aqui -->
            </div>
   <section id="msgbar"></section>
   <footer id="footer">Rodapé</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which one?the one with title? or please give little bit more info...thank you

Comment: I'm going to, hold on :), it's the gap above the scrolling bar

Comment: is it ok if i change the css of table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowing to change the css of table then do this.

change width from  100% to 102% in this line `.scrollingtable > div > div > table`

and you will see there won't be any design issue but your space will be covered.

I know i should not increase the size more then 100% but i hope it will solve your issue till you won't get better answer.

Comment: sure and if you get any problem then let me know..thanx

Comment: Could a <div> be better? because the percentage problem is that, it changes if I resize the table (but Thank you anyway, for spending your time to help)

Comment: @Calne, did not get your problem while resizing the table?any issue then please let me know..i will try more to give better solution :)

Comment: Actually, that fixed it up, I'm going to change the design to make your idea work, thank you so much for your attention and efforts to help me! :)